# eval php or asp code with c#, is possible?

Tags: c#, eval

hello
I am writing a c# comand line application which interacts with mysql db. I read some text on the db that may be php code or asp code. Is there any way to eval or interpretate this code inside c#? Ex:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   String phpcode="$test='THIS IS A TEST';return $test";
   String res=EVAL(phpcode);//or aspcode or some other not compiled language
   Console.WriteLine(res);
   //res="THIS IS A TEST";
}
```

Comment: I'd personally be interesting in *why* you're doing this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have c# apps(tasks) that runs once a day that must do the same things that my web apps do, read database and eval some code. It's a little complex to explain here all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.

However, most languages have interpreters available.

For example, you can run `PHP.exe` using `Process.Start`.

Comment: It that what I was thinking as last solution.